# Program crashed when using the function CPLString in GDAL

Tags: gdal

When I use the function CPLString in GDAL, the program crashes. Why is this happening? (I use GDAL Library in vs2012 with C++). 
For example:

```
   const char* str = "Test";
   CPLString cplString(str);
   cplString.tolower();
```

Comment: The CPLString is Inherited from std: string,and the function use win32API,why the program crashed?